# Rails ActiveRecord not finding correct user

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm building an app in which a user `has_one :profile` and a profile `belongs_to :user` but am scratching my head as to why it is looking for the `user_id` and not the `profile_id` when i'm on the profile show page. The error i'm getting is

```
Couldn't find User with 'id'=15

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @profile = @user.profile
  end
```

I have some polymorphic relationships going on with a Subject model. A profile can have many subjects and basically on the subject show page i want to link up the user that created the subject, and click to go to that user's profile page. Sorry if that was hard to understand, please find the code below.

### users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include UserCreateHelper

  skip_before_action :require_login, only: [:new, :create], raise: false

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @profile = @user.profile
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = sign_up(user_params)

    if @user.valid?
      sign_in(@user)
      create_user_profile(current_user)
      redirect_to profile_path(current_user)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
  end
end
```

Here I am creating an instance of a profile on user signup and redirecting to their new profile page to fill in their details. This step works fine.

### profiles_controller.rb

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @profile = @user.profile
  end

  def update
    if @profile = current_user.profile
      @profile.update(profile_params)
      redirect_to profile_path(current_user)
    end
  end


  private
  def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:bio, :user_id)
  end
end
```

The profiles show method above is the one creating the issue.

### views/profiles/show.html.erb

```
<div>
  <p>Hi <%= @user.email %></p>
  <% if @profile.bio %>
    <hr>
    <p><%= @profile.bio %></p>
  <% else %>
    <p>Fill out the rest of your profile!</p>
    <%= render partial: 'profiles/form', locals: {type: @profile} %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<hr>
<%= render partial: 'subjects/subject', locals: {subjectable: @profile} %>
<%= render partial: 'subjects/form', locals: {subjectable: @profile} %>
<%= render partial: 'locations/location', locals: {locationable: @profile} %>
<%= render partial: 'locations/form', locals: {locationable: @profile} %>
```

The above polymorphic associations work fine if in the profiles controller show I remove `@user = User.find(params[:id])` (i have also tried changing it to params[:user_id]) but to no avail. As i said, removing this line allows me to add the subjects fine, signup as another user and again add subjects fine, on the subjects index/all_subjects page list the subjects fine also, but when i try to link up the user who created the subject to go to their profile page it fails.

### views/subjects/all_subjects.html.erb

```
<% @all_subjects.each do |subject| %>
  <p><%= subject.title %> | Created by <%= link_to subject.user.email, profile_path(subject.user) %>, <%= time_ago_in_words(subject.created_at) + ' ago' %></p>
<% end %>
```

I know that's long winded but any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm happy to link the github repos if it would help.

### schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160612114642) do

  create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "locationable_type"
    t.integer  "locationable_id"
    t.string   "suburb"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
    t.index ["locationable_type", "locationable_id"], name: "index_locations_on_locationable_type_and_locationable_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_locations_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.text     "bio"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_profiles_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "subjects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "subjectable_type"
    t.integer  "subjectable_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.index ["subjectable_type", "subjectable_id"], name: "index_subjects_on_subjectable_type_and_subjectable_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_subjects_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",           null: false
    t.string   "password_digest", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misusing Rails' link helpers. This line...

```
profile_path(subject.user)
```

Needs to read

```
profile_path(subject.user.profile)
```

The `profile_path` helper expects its argument **to be a profile**, not a user. It's using the ID of the user record, for which there is no matching profile ID, hence your "user not found" error.

On the other side of things, you shouldn't be doing this in your **Profiles** controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @profile = @user.profile
end
```

If anything, you should be doing the opposite:

```
def show      
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  @user = @profile.user
end
```

In the context of the profiles controller, `params[:id]` will be the ID of a profile record, not a user record.

Comment: Thankyou so much @meagar . Thankyou for not only solving the problem but also take the time to explain the process behind what is happening. Everything you've said makes complete sense.